# Multiple level inheritance in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I’m trying to build my model with JPA but i’m facing an issue and i can’t find an easy solution.
OK so let’s say i store in my database movies, tv series and tv episodes. I have one table  storing the three types. Right now i have one discriminator column with those three types. In java i have one abstract class and Movie, TVSerie and TVEpisode extend that class.

I would like to be able to retrieve TV elements (TVSerie and TVEpisode) at once, for instance with a search request. 
I’ve thought about using a second discriminator column on a TVElement class like this :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
public abstract class Element{
  ...
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("tv")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="subtype")
public class TVElement extends Element{
  ...
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("episode")
public class TVEpisode extends TVElement{
  ...
}
```

However this solution does not seem to work.

What would be the best way to have a 2 level inheritance in jpa ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously do not need the second `@DiscriminatorColumn` on the subclass.

TVElement is not abstract, so something like this in hql should be fine

```
from TVElement tvElement where ...
```

it should fetch the sub-type as well. Your classes should something similar to this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
@Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.IMPLICIT)
@MappedSuperClass
public abstract class Element{
  ...
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("tv")
public class TVElement extends Element{
  ...
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("episode")
public class TVEpisode extends TVElement{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Well, i don't see how subtype could be retrieved if i don't have a discriminator column. A request " from TVElement tvElement ..." only gives me TVElements. The line @DiscriminatorValue("episode") is also pointless if i remove @DiscriminatorColumn(name="subtype") on parent class.

Comment: what's your JPA provider?

Comment: Great! I misunderstood that jpa was fetching the discriminator values of the children classes. I don't think @Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.IMPLICIT) and
@MappedSuperClass are needed

Comment: PolymorphismType.IMPLICIT is the default value, you can safely omit it, but I suggest that you use MappedSupperClass. Take a look at the API javadocs